# Capistrano bower rails deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bower

I have installed bower in the app server and I am able to run bundle exec rake bower:install in any release or in current directory. But when I'm trying the same while cap production deploy, the following error is repeated.

Command:

```
cd /home/deploy/apps/xxxx/releases/20150910064532 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake bower:install CI=true
```

Bower not found! You can install Bower using Node and npm:
DEBUG [68147ae5] $ npm install bower -g
DEBUG [68147ae5] For more info see http://bower.io/

config in deploy.rb

```
namespace :bower do
  desc 'Install bower'
  task :install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute :rake, 'bower:install CI=true'
      end
    end
  end
end
before 'deploy:compile_assets', 'bower:install'
```